# how to calculate behavioural overlaps between data from 2 dataframes?

Tags: r

So I have 2 dataframes: 1 for each individuals. The dataframe includes Time, Subject (male or female), Behaviour and Status (does the behaviour starts or ends). Here examples:

Dataframe for female:

```
Time    Subject  Behaviour  Status
20.652  F    stateTSp   START
46.400  F    stateTSp   STOP
46.687  F    FOR        START
49.436  F    FOR        STOP
49.437  F    stateTSp   START
52.404  F    stateTSp   STOP
52.405  F    FOR        START
53.154  F    FOR        STOP
53.155  F    stateTSp   START
59.151  F    stateTSp   STOP
59.152  F    FOR        START
60.151  F    FOR        STOP
60.152  F    stateTSp   START
64.651  F    stateTSp   STOP
64.652  F    FOR        START
67.201  F    TSp        START
68.201  F    TSp        STOP
68.902  F    FOR        STOP
68.903  F    stateTSp   START
78.698  F    stateTSp   STOP
79.404  F    FOR        START
80.903  F    FOR        STOP
80.904  F    stateTSp   START
89.903  F    stateTSp   STOP
89.904  F    FOR        START
93.947  F    TSp        START
94.947  F    TSp        STOP
97.547  F    TSp        START
98.547  F    TSp        STOP
101.297 F    TSp        START
102.297 F    TSp        STOP
103.902 F    TSp        START
104.902 F    TSp        STOP
108.151 F    FOR        STOP
108.152 F    stateTSp   START
111.902 F    stateTSp   STOP
111.903 F    FOR        START
113.402 F    FOR        STOP
113.403 F    stateTSp   START
116.404 F    stateTSp   STOP
116.405 F    FOR        START
118.404 F    FOR        STOP
118.405 F    stateTSp   START
121.404 F    stateTSp   STOP
121.405 F    NI     START
125.296 F    NI     STOP
125.796 F    stateTSp   START
134.404 F    stateTSp   STOP
134.405 F    FOR        START
136.154 F    FOR        STOP
136.155 F    stateTSp   START
139.754 F    stateTSp   STOP
139.755 F    FOR        START
143.660 F    FOR        STOP
143.661 F    NI     START
149.047 F    NI     STOP
```

Dataframe for the male:

```
Time    Subject  Behaviour  Status
20.652  M    NI     START
23.440  M    NI     STOP
23.441  M    FOR        START
32.435  M    TSp        START
33.435  M    TSp        STOP
40.934  M    FOR        STOP
40.935  M    NI     START
43.186  M    NI     STOP
43.187  M    FOR        START
46.363  M    FOR        STOP
46.364  M    NI     START
51.364  M    NI     STOP
51.365  M    FOR        START
64.363  M    FOR        STOP
64.364  M    NI     START
72.613  M    NI     STOP
72.614  M    FOR        START
75.361  M    FOR        STOP
75.362  M    NI     START
81.861  M    NI     STOP
81.862  M    FOR        START
90.861  M    FOR        STOP
90.862  M    NI     START
95.862  M    NI     STOP
95.863  M    FOR        START
97.862  M    FOR        STOP
97.863  M    NI     START
142.361 M    NI     STOP
142.362 M    FOR        START
146.409 M    FOR        STOP
146.410 M    NI     START
149.047 M    NI     STOP
```

From this, I want to calculate when they:
- both do the same behaviour
- one does TS (whether TSp or stateTSp) and the other FOR

Finally, I would like to be able to represent it graphically: x axis as time and colored lines representing male and females behaviours independently.

I don't know how can I make R consider the dataframes as continu time intervals where I can compare what's inside..

If you could help me to face my ignorance would be very nice ^^

Comment: Can you please offer some data? You can also use the output from the `dput()` function.

Comment: the data are the dataframe I put in the question. I do not have anything more, but I have plenty of those ^^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
 # Sample DF
 Time <- c(20.652, 46.400, 46.686, 49.436)
 Subject <- c("F", "F", "F", "F")
 Behavior <- c("Working", "Working", "Sleeping", "Working")

 # renaming columns for both DF's
 df_f <- data.frame(Time, Subject, Behavior) %>% 
   dplyr::rename(Female = Subject, Behavior_F = Behavior)

 Time <- c(20.652, 46.400, 46.686, 49.436)
 Subject <- c("M", "M", "M", "M")
 Behavior <- c("Sleeping", "Working", "Sleeping", "Sleeping")

 df_m <- data.frame(Time, Subject, Behavior) %>% 
   dplyr::rename(Male = Subject, Behavior_M = Behavior)


 df_total <- df_f %>% 
   # merging df by Time (assuming all times are presented in both DF's)
   dplyr::left_join(df_m, by = "Time") %>% 
   # you can create a vairable depending on the same behavior 
   dplyr::mutate(Same_Behavior = case_when(
      # compare it directly if the naming of the behavior would be the same
      Behavior_F == Behavior_M ~ 1,
      # in this way you can check for same behavior, if its not the same value
      Behavior_F == "Working" & Behavior_M == "Working" ~  1,
      # everything else gets a 0 or what ever you want for "not same behavior"
      TRUE ~ 0))
```

The result looks like this:

```
    Time    Female Behavior_F Male Behavior_M Same_Behavior
 1 20.652      F    Working    M   Sleeping             0
 2 46.400      F    Working    M    Working             1
 3 46.686      F   Sleeping    M   Sleeping             1
 4 49.436      F    Working    M   Sleeping             0
```

Comment: the problem is that, as in the example, the times are not the same. So we should make R understand that time is a continuous verctor and that he should analse the times as intervals.

Comment: The Variable `Time` should be of type double, I guess. If so, the x-axis will be already scaled continuously. I don't see any problems here.

Comment: it is, but the two dataframes are for different individuals and they don't do behaviours at the same moment

Comment: It is possible to make plots with ggplot where you can "ignore" NA's. However, I a Barplot would be much better: Percentage of the same behavior at the same time. Why do you even want a line plot for that information?

Comment: it was in the idea to visualize behaviours over time. If it is not possible then a barplot would be ok. But first I need to calculate the overlaps